# What is the probability of drawing an ace, a king, a queen, and 2 2's from a deck of 52 cards?

Tags: probability

If order did matter, the probability would be 4/52*4/51*4/50*4/49*3/48, but what if order didn't matter?

Would I multiply the result by 5 nPr 5 or 5! to account for all potential permutations?

Comment: You would multiply with $\frac{5!}{2!}$ because the $2$'s are repeated twice.

Comment: Oh, I see so the order of the 2's wouldn't matter because they're both identical. So it's like removing 2 nPr 2.

Comment: Yes exactly. See [permuatations of alike objects](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/probability/permutations-repeated-items.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order didn't matter, then the probability would be equal to
$$
\frac{{4\choose1}{4\choose1}{4\choose1}{4\choose2}}{{52\choose 5}}=\frac{5!}{2!}\biggl(\frac4{52}\cdot\frac4{51}\cdot\frac4{50}\cdot\frac{4}{49}\cdot\frac 3{48}\biggr),
$$
which is exactly what Sabyasachi wrote in the comments.